# Typescipt: intersection for setting default props in react

Tags: reactjs, typescript

[image]

I want to use intersection so I dont have to explicitly write every type of my defaultProps but rather take it's type from my declared variable, is that possible? As you can see in my code example even thought myProp is set as nullable, it isn't accepting null value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An intersection combines existing types meaning all the types on both object are present. You cannot use the type of the declared variable to define `testProps` if its a union of multiple types, as when you set the default value you bind it to a particular type.

Comment: sorry i couldn't understand, why not? it seems to have overrriden my explicit typing for myProp? what does setting defaultProp has to do with typing?

Comment: @Lelouch you're intersecting the type of ``defaultProp``. So the type of ``myProp`` is infered as string from ``defaultProp`` and overwrites the explicit type